# How to add new column before first column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, backend

[As per image, How to add new column before first column in mysql ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAFec.png)

Comment: If the relative columns posession effects on your code than your code is wrong and must be rewrited.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD [COLUMN] column_name column_definition FIRST;
```

Shamelessly stolen from the [first hit](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-add-column/) on Google.

Comment: Exactly : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=628823a9265644f9715b2dd26ce5d925

Comment: this is cool !!

Answer (score 0):

I believe a better approach would be to add an **primary key**, **auto incredient** id column.

In PHPMyAdmin, select your table > Structure > (bottom) add X=1 columns at Y=the beggining of table.
Name that column "ID" and set **Index = Primary** and click "**A_I**" (auto incredient).

This way now, every time you add a record to that table, even if you INSERT id as NULL, **you will have a unique id**. **You can use it then according to your needs.**

For example, this way, if you want to see users, **from the newst ones to the oldest ones (bigger id -> smaller id = DESC)**, as you ask in your question, you can easily run :

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Have fun !

---

[edit]

its just another method, the Skrrp's answer is really cool if you cant change your approach, still having indexes its a good idea to be able to handle your data.